# Exported object is empty

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm struggling since 2 days on something that shouldn't block me.

Basically, I'm building a nodeJS app that uses Express.
In my main file (located in my root folder), i'm exporting some variables/consts, for the purpose of the example I replaced them like this :

```
// ./index.js
const test = 'test'
module.exports = { test }
... some express initialization/routers
```

I then have another file that I want to use the "test" variable in, so I require my main file :

```
// ./aaa/bbb/ccc/test.js
const { test } = require('../../../index);
const myRouter = require('express').Router();

myRouter.get('/', function (req, res){
    console.log(test) // undefined
})
```

I don't really know why it would be undefined as I correctly exported it, and "imported" it through my require statement.

I also tried "consoling" the whole object that I should receive, and it's empty : {}

EDIT : my "main" script that i'm executing is indeed index.js, but I highly doubt it's the reason of the problem

I can't really find out what could be the problem, and I need to export some variable to access them in my project

Thanks!

Comment: If you console.log test outside of myRouter, does it work?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried that too and I'm still getting an undefined/empty object (tried console.log both the exporter variable and the whole object, none succeeds)

Comment: What about inside of index.js before you export it? Is that console.log undefined too?

Comment: Inside index.js, if i console.log(test), it's working, really can't find out what could be the problem with those empty exported objects...

Comment: There's not much to work with here.. It looks correct. Maybe just for kicks try `module.exports.test = test`. I'm sure there's something very simple slightly off. You could also create a mock in codesandbox.io which will give us more to work with.

Comment: For some reason this actually works, not the best notation but well I guess I'll have to stick with this... thanks!

Comment: Lol. Agree. I think you must have a typo somewhere because it should work the way you had it.

Comment: I supposed so so I literally copy and pasted another export that's working, and it's not working haha, super weird

Comment: Maybe there's a hidden character somewhere that you copied over. I would erase it all and type it out again and I bet it would work. If you `cat -v` the file on the command line it will show you any hidden characters.

Comment: I already checked for hidden characters and nothing unusual haha, so weird

Answer (score 0):

I think you did it right. The problem may be that `es6` features are not acceptable on your node version. Try it like: `module.exports = { test:test }`.

Comment: Hey! I tried it too and sadly it's not working either :( i'm using node v12.18.0 btw

Comment: Hi - I'm reviewing your answer because it's a standard process for a First Posts. One suggestion that may be helpful: when including a code snippet as part of your post, you may want to delimit the code snippet with the character: ``(before and after)``. Using this technique will apply code formatting (as in: `module.exports = { test:test }`), which makes the code easier to read and allows you to clearly mark the exact text you wish to  include as part of the code snippet.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm referring to the backtick (`) character (located on the upper left of most keyboards).